# Can't find xml id while inflating view

Tags: android, android-widget, android-layout, android-xml

I'm trying to inflate an custom alertdialog and encountered something strange.

```
layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.call_or_sms_dialog,(ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.contacts));
```

The inflate() method takes 2 argument, the resource to be inflated and the optional view to be the parent of the generated dialog. My problem comes at the optional view part.

I can't find the id of the root view from findViewById(R.id.contacts). "contacts" is a xml file that contains the controls for this particular activity. I was able to reference some other xml file of other activities but just couldn't reference this contacts.xml.

I've tried doing the "clean" build on Eclipse and regenerating the R.java but still it does not help. Is there any way to manually generate the ID of "contacts.xml" instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > "contacts" is a xml file that contains the controls for this particular activity

If it's an XML, you cannot access it by using `R.id`; but something like `R.xml` or `R.layout`. Of course, if you are using `findViewById` you must pass a valid id (something referenced by `R.id`). So... what you have to do is give an ID to the view that you want to reference; for instance:

```
<ViewGroup
   android:id="@+id/contacts"
   blah
```

Also, keep in mind that, if you are using the `findViewById` method directly, the ID must be part of the current layout (I mean the layout set in `setContentView`). If the ID does not belong to the current layout you will want to execute something like `referenceToTheViewContainingTheIDResource.findViewById()` instead.

Comment: Thank you Christian. It seems like R.layout do the trick. I have another activity that's doing the same thing but that layout can be referenced thru R.id. It's an xml file too. In fact, I'm able to reference to 2 of the xml files that I'm currently doing. Why is that so?

Comment: There's no way that you can reference a layout using `R.id`. If an ID of an XML resource is called in the same way as a layout, it could seem that you are referencing the layout via `R.id`, but actually you are not :P

Comment: I see. So that means I better be referencing by R.layout instead right? Thank you once again, how I wish there is a +2 button. ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
Please try this code:

LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("SET YOUR TITLE");

View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.call_or_sms_dialog, null);
v  = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.contacts);
alertDialog.setView(view);
```

Answer (score 0):

The second argument is meant to be an existing view, not the root view of the layout you are inflating. Is this the problem? You can always just pass `null` as the second argument.

Comment: Thank you Ted for replying. I tried putting null but it doesn't work. There was an exception to it.